# Can a state impose additional qualifications for Presidential candidates wishing to appear on the ballot?

Tags: us-constitution

Suppose, for example, that Colorado wants to pass a law that bars convicted criminals from appearing on the Presidential ballot (so Colorado voters can't vote for a Presidential candidate who is convicted of a crime)

Would the Presidential Qualifications Clause of the US constitution prohibit Colorado from passing this law?

Comment: Technically, the constitution doesn't prohibit any legislature from passing any law. It just prevents incompatible laws from being enforced.

Comment: Highly related: [US State laws about qualifications to be a candidate](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/82565/)

Answer (score 3):

It would not prohibit Colorado from passing the law, but it could prohibit implementing the law. SCOTUS rulings (Powell v. McCormack, 395 U.S. 486; Term Limits, 514 U.S. 779) establish that neither Congress nor the States can require additional qualifications of federal candidates beyond those listed in the Constitution. The relevant question is whether a law imposes an additional "qualification" on a candidate for president. Every state imposes at least one requirement on a person seeking to be a candidate on the ballot in a state: they must somehow "register" as a candidate. So the Qualifications Clause is not interpreted to mean "anybody can run for president as long as age and natural-born". The [Anderson-Burdick doctrine](https://www.scotusblog.com/election-law-explainers/the-anderson-burdick-doctrine-balancing-the-benefits-and-burdens-of-voting-restrictions/) allows certain kinds of requirements to be imposed on candidates, namely those that relate to a state's interest on properly managing elections. A no-felon law would clearly go way beyond the accepted state interest (regarding management of elections) reflected in Anderson-Burdick, and would be found to be as unconstitutional as requiring a candidate for president to have a law degree, or prohibiting a candidate from having a law degree.